# Questions about the proof of the Sturm oscillation theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, sturm-liouville

I'm trying to understand the proof of the Sturm oscillation theorem and I hit the roadblock.

**Theorem:** Let $E_0<E_1<\dots$ be the eigenvalues of $H=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+V(x)$ on $L^2(0,a)$ with boundary conditions $u(0)=u(a)=0$. Then $u(x,E_n)$ has exactly $n$ zeros in $(0,a)$.

**Part of the proof:** 
Suppose $u_n$ has $m$ zeros $x_1<\dots<x_m$ in $(0,a)$. Let $v_0,\dots,v_m$ be the function $u_n$ restricted successively to $(0,x_1),(x_1,x_2),...,(x_m,a)$. The $v$'s are continuous and piecewise $C^1$ with $v_l(0)=v_l(a)=0$. Thus they lie in the quadratic form domain of $H$ and 
$$
<v_j,Hv_k>=\int_0^a v'_j v'_k + \int_0^a Vv_jv_k=\delta_{jk}E\int_0^a v_j^2dx
$$
since if $j=k$, we can integrate by parts and use $-u''+Vu=Eu$.
It follows that for any $v$ in the span of $v_j$'s, $<v,Hv>=E\|v\|^2$, so by the variational principle, $H$ has at least $m+1$ eigenvalues in $(-\infty, E_n]$, that is, $n+1\geq m+1$

**Questions:**

1. Why is it possible to express $<v_j,Hv_k>$ as in the formula above and how the expression is integrated by parts?
2. What is the variational principle mentioned above that allows to determine the number of eigenvalues in the interval $(-\infty, E_n]$?

Comment: The integration by parts is used to convert second derivative to first derivative operator for the first integral in the formula.

Comment: @Chee Han I don't see, why we can't directly put $-v_k''+V(x)v_k$ under the integral and why we need the integration by parts.

Comment: That's only for the $Hv_k$ part, you still need to take the inner product between $v_j$ and $Hv_k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Question 1

By definition
$$
\newcommand{\ip}[2]{\left\langle#1,#2\right\rangle}
\ip{v_j}{Hv_k}
=
\int_0^a(-v_jv_k''+Vv_jv_k).
$$
The first term is in fact $\int_{x_j}^{x_{j+1}}-v_jv_k''$.
On this interval we integrate by parts as usual.
The boundary terms vanish because $v_j(x_j)=v_j(x_{j+1})=0$.
Since $v_j$ (and $v_j'$) is supported on this interval, it makes no difference to expand it to the whole $[0,1]$, so
$$
\ip{v_j}{Hv_k}
=
\int_0^a(v_j'v_k'+Vv_jv_k).
$$
This is the first equality.

The other equality is different.
The functions $v_j$ are supported on different intervals so $\ip{v_j}{Hv_k}$ has to be zero when $j\neq k$.
It then remains to calculate $\ip{v_k}{Hv_k}$.
This is nothing but $\int_{x_k}^{x_{k+1}}v_kHv_k$.
Now $Hv_k=E_nv_k$ on this interval.
This gives you
$$
\ip{v_j}{Hv_k}
=
E_n\delta_{jk}\int_{x_k}^{x_{k+1}}v_k^2.
$$
You can replace the integral with that from $0$ to $a$ since $v_k$ is zero outside the interval in the formula above.

So for the first equality, integrate by parts, and for the second, use the eigenfunction property.

### Question 2

There are many variational principles out there, so I can only guess which one is meant here.
Consult the material you are using for an exact formulation.
My guess is this:
If there is an $M$-dimensional space of functions $v$ with $\ip{v}{Hv}=E\ip{v}{v}$, then $H$ has to have at least $M$ eigenvalues $\leq E$.
This applied to $M=m+1$ and $E=E_n$ gives the inequality in your proof.

### Formatting comment

This is beside the point, but I can't help commenting.
Please do not use the less and greater than symbols (`<` and `>`) for the inner product.
They are designed to be binary relations, so their looks and spacing don't fit the use in inner products.
Instead, use the angle brackets `\langle` and `\rangle`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! In your explanation $M=m+1$ because there are $m+1$ functions $v_m$? Where could I read about the variational principle you mentioned (is it some form of min-max theorem) ?

Comment: @Konstantin Yes, because of the $m+1$ functions $v_0,\dots,v_m$. If you found that proof in a book, I expect to find details of the principle in the same book. As I said in the answer, my formulation is only a guess, and I don't know any source that would discuss it. Can you make a separate resource request about such a theorem if it's not included in whatever source you are using? If you do, please link to (or otherwise cite) the source where you found the proof, and give a link to this question for context.