# Sturm oscillation theorem

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, boundary-value-problem, sturm-liouville

I am preparing for a competitive exam and there is a theorem in my syllabus(in particular in ODE)which is named as **Sturm oscillation theorem**.But I am unable to find this theorem in online stuff,moreover the book I am following does not have this topic.Can someone guide me and state the theorem?

Thanks!

Comment: [Sturm-Picone comparison theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Picone_comparison_theorem).

Comment: @mattos, but I asked about oscillation  theorem ,not comparison theorem

Comment: Sorry, I read the question incorrectly. The theorem you are after is stated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2213778/questions-about-the-proof-of-the-sturm-oscillation-theorem).

Comment: @mattos,yes I saw this post but there are few things which I don't  understandstand,...first of all what is V?secondly what is differential equation here?It is written that equation is $H=-\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+V(x)$ but this is not a equation, rather it is the definition  of schrodinger Operator H.

Comment: It's the Dirichlet eigenvalue problem for the operator $H$ (where $V$ is some given function), so the differential equation is $-u''(x) + V(x) \, u(x) = Eu(x)$ for $0<x<a$, with boundary conditions $u(0)=u(a)=0$. And $u(x,E_n)$ denotes the $n$th eigenfunction (the one corresponding to the $n$th eigenvalue $E=E_n$).

Comment: @Hans Lundmark;If we take domain of interval to be $[0,1]$ and $V(x)=0$,then our equation becomes regular SL-EVP $u"+Eu=0$ with boundary conditions $u(0)=u(1)=0$.On solving,solution is $u_n(x)=a\sin {n\pi x}$ corresponding to $n$th eigen value $E_n=n^2\pi^2,n\in\mathbb{N}$ where $a$ is some arbitrary constant.In this case $n$th eigen function  $u_n(x)=a\sin {n\pi x}$ has only exactly $n-1$ solutions in $(0,1)$,but theorem guarantees exactly  $n$ solutions.

Comment: Note that the theorem is formulated in that question with the eigenvalues numbered starting with $E_0$. So $E_n = (n+1)^2 \pi^2$ in this case.

Comment: @Hans Lundmark;Thank you so much for guiding me,....one last question, is there any existence  theorem on Dirichlet eigenvalue problem?There was a question in which the equation is $-y''(x) + (1+x)\, y(x) = \lambda y(x)$.The question  was this equation  has non zero solution if $\lambda\in ?$.The answer is $\lambda\in (2,\infty)$,could you please help me?

Comment: Perhaps you could post that as a separate question. But you also need to state what the interval is (i.e., at which points $a$ and $b$ you require $y(a)=y(b)=0$).

Comment: @Hans Lundmark; I forgot to t write boundaries and boundary conditions, the interval is (0,1) with boundary conditions y(0)=y(1)=0